# refresh after db change?

Tags: frameworks, entity, entity-framework-5

Although I've seen this discussed in various contexts, I can't seem to find an answer to my scenario.

I'm a noob to EF and I started a new project using the database first scenario and the "reverse engineer" code tool.  I made some changes to my db and, out of "desperation" ran the same tool all over again, which seemed to work OK but made me vaguely nervous.

I've seen discussion of using a "refresh from database" tool but not only can't I find it, I can't find an edmx file in my solution at all. I'm going to need to add an entire new table to my db and I want to make sure I'm following the proper procedure to update afterwards.

What is the procedure I should take to update my database?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the database and now want to update/recreate the model just rightclick on the EF designer surface and select "Update Model From Database". If you are OK starting from scratch for some reason usually it is OK to just delete the edmx file and then right click on your project -> Add New Item (or Ctlr + Shift + A) and add a new ADO.NET Data Entity Model. Then in the wizard you need to select the model from the database and point to your database. You want to follow the steps above if you don't have the .edmx file in your project as well.